# Hyperlink to files based on cell content

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I need to insert hyperlinks to an entire column based on the contents of that cell.

```
 Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "http://FILE LOCATION/" & "A2"
```

So if A2 contains 0106-15-9562 I need it to hyperlink to

```
"http://FILE LOCATION/0106-15-9562"
```

...And so forth down the entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add cell, "http://example.com/" & cell.Value
Next
```

Comment: So simple and executed perfectly! Thank you so much!